# Showing that $f_1(x,t) \leq f_2(x,t)$ for solutions of $f_t+f_x=1$ if $f_1(x,0) \leq f_2(x,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be two solutions of the equation $f_t+f_x=1$ in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_1(x,0) \leq f_2(x,0)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Show that $f_1(x,t)\leq f_2(x,t)$ in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$

My attempt:
I was thinking that $f(x,0)=g(x)$ is a typical initial value condition.
Solving the initial value problem yields:
$f(x,t)=g(x-t)+\int_0^t 1 ds$

This means that $f_1,f_2$ have the form:

$f_1(x,t)=f_1(x-t,0) + \int_0^t 1 ds$

$f_2(x,t)=f_2(x-t,0) + \int_0^t 1 ds$

So for arbitrary $t,x$:
$f_1(x-t,0) \leq f_2(x-t,0)$ and the integral part is the same for $f_1$ and $f_2$, thus $f_1(x,t)\leq f_2(x,t)$

Is my attempt correct?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how you obtain $f(x, t) = g(x-t) + \int_0^t 1 ds$.

Here is my attempt: put $h = f_2 - f_1$. Then $h$ is a solution of the equation $h_t + h_x = 0$, which satisfies $h(x,0) \geq 0 $ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We want to show $h(x,t) \geq 0 $ hold for all $(x, t) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Let $g(x,t) = h(x+t, t)$. Then $g_t(x,t) = h_x(x+t, t) + h_t(x+t,t) = 0 $. This shows $h_c(t) := h(c+t, t)$ is a constant function for given $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Now let $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ be given. Put $c = a-b$. Then $h(a,b) = h( c+ b , b) = h_c(b)= h_c(0)=h(c,0) \geq 0 $ as desired.